# How do you create a copy of a VS2005 solution while disassociating it from VSS?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

I copied the root folder to my desktop, deleted all files in that folder or under that folder if the file was a VSS file, opened the project, confirmed that I wanted to removed VSS integration and still my web project but not the referenced projects in the solution were tied to VSS and they changed my checkout folder in VSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also remove the source control related settings from the sln file.

Answer (score 1):

Look for hidden .vss files.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I already had my Windows Explorer options set to show hidden files and folders. I think that there are references in some of the project files that refer to VSS. I remember seeing a long article about to break a project's  VSS  intergration and it was far from straight forward. I lost the link and frankly, was hoping for an easier solution. Deleting all VSS- extensioned files wasn't enough.